# Scraping ASPX page with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scape an aspx site. My script just produces:

[]

Process finished with exit code 0

My code is below:

```
import requests
import bs4



url = "https://www.brightmlshomes.com/Listing/ListingSearch.aspx"

page = requests.get(url)

src = page.text

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

final_results = []

for tmp in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'mapsearch-singleprop mapsearch-map-singleprop included '
                                         'slick-already-processed'}):

    final_results.append(tmp['data-price'])

print(final_results)
```

Is this not working because it's an ASPX page?

Comment: To get the data from that page you need to send a post http requests in this url `https://www.brightmlshomes.com/Include/AJAX/MapSearch/GetListingPins.aspx?` with appropriate `params` and `payload`. Try using dev tools to observe how the requests is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Being an ASPX page shouldn't make a difference, since the underlying page source is still `html`. That being said you should probably use `html.parser` rather than `lxml` in your `BeautifulSoup` constructor.

The reason why the script returns no results is that there are no matches in the page source `html` for the class that you specify in your `find_all` function. You should look at the page source to determine the right keywords to use.

Comment: with `html.parser` and with a matching class in the html page like `mapsearch-singleprop mapsearch-map-singleprop included slick-already-processed` also results in `[]`. Looks like ASPX needs special handling.

Comment: There exists no class identifier `"mapsearch-singleprop mapsearch-map-singleprop included slick-already-processed"` on that page.

Comment: @PApostol That tag does exist but it seems to be nested deep in the page. This is what I see when copy js path:

document.querySelector("#mapsearch-results-body > div:nth-child(1)")

Maybe I'm not understanding the concept well.

Comment: @SachinDangol I used the html parser as well.